# how to add default search condition(or predicate) using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Overview:**
All the tables of my database contains a column `SiteID` which is a reference to table "`Sites`". The idea is to partition the tables by site. So from my code I would like to pass this `SiteID` as default search condition

**Problem**
I set this `SiteID` when ever user logs in to my website.
In my Generic Repository I have method `GetQuery<TEntity>()` that returns `IQueryable<TEntity>` object. Is there a way in the following method I can append this default search condition?

Note: I have a feeling that this is more kind of design related issue than entity framework.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return from query in DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
               join site in DbContext.Set<Site>() on "JOIN_CONDITION??" 
               equals Site.SiteID
               select query;
}
```

Regards,
Assam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all entities in your application have column `SiteID` then create some interface which will define SiteID property

```
public interface ISiteDependent // of course consider better domain specific name
{
   int SiteID { get; set; }
}
```

And make your entities implement it. Use this interface as generic constraint:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() 
    where TEntity : class, ISiteDependent
{
     return from query in DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
            join site in DbContext.Set<Site>() 
                 on query.SiteID equals site.SiteID // SiteID is available now
            select query;
}
```

Comment: Well i had already tried that but got following error.
The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: @AssamZafar looks like you are missing `class` constraint. It should be also specified, see the example

Comment: thanks i actually missed the class constraint. BTW just for the sake of opinion given you had to implement would you also had done similar way?

Comment: @AssamZafar well if you need to store all data for all sites in single database, then I think approach is good. BTW I'd probably hide this joining into the repositories.

Comment: Logically your suggestion makes a lot of sense but don't you think by putting them in respective repositories will yield to much of look alike code(duplication)?